# Include react-native component in vanilla React app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

It sounds like a weird question. It is. But is it possible to do something like this in a react app that I instantiated with create-react-app?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
...
```

i.e. even if I can't actually build the mobile view, I want to include it in my code to do something else with it

I only ask because I can't get around a 
`"Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native' in '/Users/...'` error, even with `react-native` in my package.json

Answer (score 1):

well... the thing is that `react-native` will only work for native apps, if you need to use those components, you will have to use an alternative such as react-native-web.

https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web

This might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `react-primitives`.

> This library attempts to propose an ideal set of primitives around
>   building React applications, regardless of Platform. In the future,
>   this could be used as a shared interface among React and React Native
>   components that don't use platform-specific APIs.

Then, you import **certain** primitives from this package. They will render in native and/or DOM.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-primitives';

export function CrossplatformComponent() {
  return <Text>Hello world</Text>
}
```